# Restructure dataframe (maybe pivot or unpivot) to have each column display the label of data based on 0's and 1's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, transform

I have survey data. The survey asks a question and the respondents pick one or more given categories for each question. The survey then asks demographic questions such as gender. The output is a dataframe with demographic information as columns and a matrix of 0's and 1's for each category in each question (0 = not selected and 1 = selected).

To help you better understand how this looks like I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Survey ID': [1,2,3],
                   'Q1_Topic A': [0,1,1], 
                   'Q1_Topic B': [1,0,1], 
                   'Q1_Topic C': [1,0,0],
                   'Q2_Topic X': [0,0,1], 
                   'Q2_Topic Y': [0,1,0], 
                   'Q2_Topic Z': [0,0,1],
                   'Gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male']
                  })
print(df)
```

I need to transform this dataframe to show me a column for each question and multiple rows for each survey depending on how many categories were chosen. Each row should have a category under the relevant question column.

Confused yet? Its hard to explain but the data should look like

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Survey ID': [1,1,2,3,3],
                   'Q1': ['B','C','A','A','B'], 
                   'Q2': [float('nan'), float('nan'), 'Y', 'X', 'Z'],
                   'Gender': ['Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male']
                    })
print(df2)
```

Basically **I need to transform df to df2.**
Note: There is a common separator of "_" for the question and topic for each column label.

As always thanks a lot for you help in advanced. Without this community I would be seriously stuck sometimes and I am learning a lot through this platform.

Comment: where is Q2_Topic A coming from? what's the logic?

Comment: Sorry it was a typeo. Question 2 now has an X, Y and Z category. Basically each question has unique categories to chose from. If they chose a category it will be a 1 if not then 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert to MultiIndex all not Q topic columns
df2 = df.set_index(['Survey ID','Gender'])
#split columns names to MultiIndex in columns
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.split(expand=True)
#reshape
df2 = df2.stack()
#filter only rows with at least one 1 per row and reshape for remove NaNs
#also replace 0 to NaNs
df2 = df2[df2.eq(1).any(axis=1)].replace(0, np.nan).stack().reset_index(level=2)

#added helper level to MultiIndex because possible duplicates by counter
df2['g'] = df2.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).cumcount()
#final reshape
df2 = (df2.set_index('g', append=True)['level_2']
          .unstack(2)
          .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
          .reset_index())

print (df2)
   Survey ID  Gender Q1_Topic Q2_Topic
0          1    Male        B      NaN
1          1    Male        C      NaN
2          2  Female        A        Y
3          3    Male        A        X
4          3    Male        B        Z
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael

Im not getting the right numbers on my real DF. My real DF is at [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/az7le1bl4121au2/Transcript_dummies.xlsx?dl=0).

I have used the same code except adjusted the split to split at '_'

I have been spending hours trying to figure out what the numbers dont add up.

Your help as always would be appreciated.

Comment: @Mish - Super, data was downloaded. Can you also get expected output or some way for test data? In another words, how I can test if output is like need or not?

Comment: Okay basically this is going into tableau for visualization. Tableau doesnt like a bunch of 0's and 1's. Each column is a topic and has it group attached to it with a '_'

@jezrael Just like the example I posted I need the output to be each group as a column and in each column will have the values of the topic in it or a null. Does this make sense?

Comment: For example. The output should have a column called "Stream 4 Topics" because it is before the "_". When i count how many times "Accessibility" comes up in my original DF i get 14 because there are 14 1's. However the output shows that in the column it is appearing 42 times which is incorrect.

Comment: @Mish - Is possible get expected output from first row?

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xw8gyqzywhu1mwv/dfforjez.xlsx?dl=0) Hee is an example. It will keep on making rows until all the topics of each group are covered and then go onto the next survey number. The same as the fictional example i posted originally.

Comment: @jezreal I am using df2.columns = df2.columns.str.split(pat = '_', expand=True) is this not correct?

Comment: @jezreal when I use df2.columns = df2.columns.str.split(pat = '_', expand=True) the output is incorrect. When i count how many times "Accessibility" comes up in my original DF i get 14 because there are 14 1's. However the output shows that in the column it is appearing 42 times which is incorrect. This is for column "Stream 4 Topics for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211540/discussion-between-jezrael-and-mish).

Answer (score 0):

How about this code? It is not fancy code, but intuitive.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Survey ID': [1,2,3],
                   'Q1_Topic A': [0,1,1], 
                   'Q1_Topic B': [1,0,1], 
                   'Q1_Topic C': [1,0,0],
                   'Q2_Topic A': [0,0,1], 
                   'Q2_Topic B': [0,1,0], 
                   'Q2_Topic C': [0,0,1],
                   'Gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male']
                  })

values = []

for ind, row in df1.iterrows():
    survey_ID = row['Survey ID']
    Gender = row['Gender']
    Q1 = row['Q1_Topic A'] * ['A'] + row['Q1_Topic B'] * ['B'] + row['Q1_Topic C'] * ['C']
    Q2 = row['Q2_Topic A'] * ['A'] + row['Q2_Topic B'] * ['B'] + row['Q2_Topic C'] * ['C']

    for i in range(max(len(Q1), len(Q2))):
        if i >= len(Q1):
            record = [survey_ID, np.nan, Q2[i], Gender]
        elif i >= len(Q2):
            record = [survey_ID, Q1[i], np.nan, Gender]
        else:
            record = [survey_ID, Q1[i], Q2[i], Gender]
        values.append(record)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = ['Survey ID', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Gender'])
```

Comment: This is okay but the real thing has many columns. 5 questions with many topics in each resulting in about 178 columns. It would be a nightmare to type the code for that.